# Opsworks Chef unable to create cron

Tags: cron, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I try to create a cron task with chef running opsworks in AWS.
I guess I have some permission problem as the write failes, but where can I increase the permission? or should I really need to increase the permission?

Chef:

```
cron 'crontest' do
  minute "0"
  hour "/2"
  day "*"
  month "*"
  weekday "*"
  command "ls"
end
```

Logs:

```
Logs from opsworks:
------------------

[2016-09-12T19:47:13+00:00] INFO: Processing cron[crontest] action create (my::crontest line 1)

================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'cron[crontest]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::Cron
----------------------
Error updating state of crontest, exit: 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/runs/de35b7b0-20ad-4903-a5b1-e8e901695b5b/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/my/recipes/crontest.rb

1: cron 'crontest' do
2:   minute "0"
3:   hour "/2"
4:   day "*"
5:   month "*"
6:   weekday "*"
7:   command "ls"
8: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/runs/de35b7b0-20ad-4903-a5b1-e8e901695b5b/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/my/recipes/crontest.rb:1:in `from_file'

cron("crontest") do
action [:create]
retries 0
retry_delay 2
default_guard_interpreter :default
minute "0"
hour "/2"
day "*"
month "*"
weekday "*"
command "ls"
user "root"
declared_type :cron
cookbook_name "my"
recipe_name "crontest"
end

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux

[2016-09-12T19:47:13+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2016-09-12T19:47:13+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2016-09-12T19:47:13+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-09-12T19:47:13+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/runs/de35b7b0-20ad-4903-a5b1-e8e901695b5b/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-09-12T19:47:13+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-09-12T19:47:13+00:00] ERROR: cron[crontest] (my::crontest line 1) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Cron: Error updating state of crontest, exit: 1
[2016-09-12T19:47:13+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)


Logs from /var/chef/runs/de35b7b0-20ad-4903-a5b1-e8e901695b5b/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
------------------
>>>> Caused by Chef::Exceptions::Cron: Error updating state of crontest, exit: 1
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.13.37/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb:232:in `write_crontab'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.13.37/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb:157:in `block in action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.13.37/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.13.37/lib/chef/provider.rb:176:in `converge_by'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.13.37/lib/chef/provider/cron.rb:156:in `action_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.13.37/lib/chef/provider.rb:145:in `run_action'
```

Comment: Is `hour "/2"` valid cron timing for the target system? Some versions of cron do not support repetition syntax. Perhaps it's failing when it attempts to validate the new crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had my own problems with an OpsWorks (Chef 12) cron job. I was trying to specify

```
weekday 'wed,fri'
```

syntax in the cron job definition, and while this was legal on the target system it triggered a bug in the Chef method. The symptom of that bug was that every time this recipe got executed the current crontab entry did not get edited/replaced, a duplicate was added beneath the original. I had half a dozen identical lines before I even noticed the problem.

I fixed my specific problem by using the

```
weekday '4,6'
```

syntax. The lesson I took away from this was, do not try to be remotely clever with your cron job recipe. Use the simplest, oldest, most boring notation possible to define your cron job.

The Chef cronjob code uses regexp to figure out which lines to add/edit. Anything that might confuse the parser should be avoided.